# Definition of Local Functor

Tags: category-theory, definition, functors

I have seen local functors being mentioned while constructing products of varieties and schemes but I couldn’t find the definition of a local functor. Any comments/reference will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you name some specific references in which you've seen it?

Comment: I was reading through the first chapter of Geometric Modular Forms by Haruzo Hida. It’s basically a review of algebraic geometry. There while constructing product of varieties I saw this